# Подскажите как уменьшить объем памяти, потребляемой прогой

Tags: c, алгоритм

Имеется задание такого вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_H 32
#define M 101
#define hashing(A) A % M

#define TUZ 1000
#define KVA 1000000000000000

struct node {
    struct node *child [2];
    long long info;
    char balance;
};

struct tree {
    struct node *root;
    short size;
};

struct tree *init_tree (void);
struct node *new_node (struct tree *, long long );
struct node *search (struct tree*, const long long );
void turn (struct node **);
struct node *insert (struct tree *, long long );
struct node *del (struct node *);
struct tree *del_tree (struct tree *);
int rm (struct tree *, long long );

int main (void)
{
    FILE *input = NULL;
    FILE *output = NULL;

    struct tree *arr [M] = {};

    int N = 0;
    long long X = 0;
    short A = 0, Ac = 0, Ad = 0;
    long long B = 0, Bc = 0, Bd = 0;

    if ((input = fopen ("input.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf ("ERROR of open file input.txt\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fscanf (input, "%i %lli %hi %lli", &N, &X, &A, &B);
    fscanf (input, "%hi %lli %hi %lli", &Ac, &Bc, &Ad, &Bd);

    if (fclose (input) != 0) {
        printf ("ERROR of exit from file input.txt\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
      arr [i] = init_tree ();
  }

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        if (search (arr [hashing (X)], X)) {
            A = (A + Ac) % TUZ;
            B = (B + Bc) % KVA;
        }
        else {
            insert (arr [hashing (X)], X);
            A = (A + Ad) % TUZ;
            B = (B + Bd) % KVA;
        }

        X = (X * A + B) % KVA;
    }

    if ((output = fopen ("output.txt", "w")) == NULL) {
        printf ("ERROR of open file ouput.txt\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fprintf (output, "%lli %hi %lli", X, A, B);

    if (fclose (output) != 0) {
        printf ("ERROR of exit from file ouput.txt\n");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) {
      arr [i] = del_tree (arr [i]);
  }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

struct tree *init_tree (void)
{
    struct tree *tree = malloc (sizeof *tree);
    tree->root = NULL;
    tree->size = 0;

    return tree;
}

struct node *new_node (struct tree *n_tree,  long long item)
{
    struct node *new = malloc (sizeof *new);
    if (new) {
        new->child [0] = new->child [1] = NULL;
        new->info = item;
        new->balance = 0;
        n_tree->size++;
    }

    return new;
}

struct node *insert (struct tree *in_tree,  long long element)
{
    struct node *in_node = in_tree->root;
    struct node **new = &in_tree->root;

    struct node **array [MAX_H] = {};//массив хранящий указатели на все пройденные ноды
    short dirs [MAX_H] = {};//массив хранящий направления движения
    short count = 0;

    for (;;) {
        if (!in_node) {
            in_node = *new = new_node (in_tree, element);
            break;
        }
        else
            if (in_node->info == element)
                return NULL;
            else {
                array [count] = new;
                dirs [count] = element > in_node->info;
                new = &in_node->child [dirs [count]];
                in_node = in_node->child [dirs [count]];
                count++;
            }
    }

    if (in_node && count) {//когда произошла вставка происходит балансировка
        for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            if ((*array [i])->balance) {//если баланс не равен нулю
                (*array [i])->balance = (dirs [i]) ? (*array [i])->balance - 1 : (*array [i])->balance + 1;//происходит изменение баланса в зависимости от направления
                if (abs ((*array [i])->balance) == 2)//выполняется поворот если надо
                    turn (array [i]);
                if (!(*array [i])->balance)//если баланс оказался равен 0, то дальнейшие корректировки не нужны
                    break;
            }
            else//если баланс узла был равен 0, то он изменяется в зависимости от направления
                (*array [i])->balance = (dirs [i]) ? -1 : 1;
        }
    }

    return in_node;
}

int rm (struct tree *rm_tree,  long long element)
{
    struct node *rm_node = rm_tree->root;
    struct node **q = &rm_tree->root;

    struct node **array [MAX_H] = {};//тоже что и во вставке
    short dirs [MAX_H] = {};
    short count = 0;

    for (;;) {
        if (!rm_node)
            return 1;
        else
            if (rm_node->info == element)
                break;
            else {
                array [count] = q;
                dirs [count] = element > rm_node->info;
                q = &rm_node->child [dirs [count]];
                rm_node = rm_node->child [dirs [count]];
                count++;
            }
    }

    if (!rm_node->child [0]) {
        *q = rm_node->child [1];
    }
    else {
        struct node *y = rm_node->child [0];

        dirs [count] = 0;//в этом случае создание массива продолжается
        array [count] = q;//в массив вводится указатель на удаляемую ноду, которая будет заменена другой
        count++;

        if (!y->child [1]) {
            y->child [1] = rm_node->child [1];

            y->balance = rm_node->balance;//удаляемая нода изменяется, но баланс остается
            *q = y;
        }
        else {
            struct node *x = y->child [1];
            short px = 0;
            px = count;
            dirs [count] = 1;//дополнение в массив указателей происходит ниже
            count++;

            while (x->child [1]) {
                dirs [count] = 1;
                array [count] = &y->child [1];
                count++;

                y = x;
                x = x->child [1];
            }

            y->child [1] = x->child [0];
            x->child [0] = rm_node->child [0];
            x->child [1] = rm_node->child [1];

            array [px] = &x->child [0];//вот оно, так как именно эта нода заменяет собой удаляемую

            x->balance = rm_node->balance;

            *q = x;
        }
    }

    for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {//опять балансировка
        if ((*array [i])->balance) {
            (*array [i])->balance = (dirs [i]) ? (*array [i])->balance + 1 : (*array [i])->balance - 1;
            if (abs ((*array [i])->balance) == 2)
                turn (array [i]);
        }
        else
            (*array [i])->balance = (dirs [i]) ? 1 : -1;

        if ((*array [i])->balance)
            break;
    }

    rm_tree->size--;

    free (rm_node);
    rm_node = NULL;

    return 0;
}

struct node *search (struct tree *stree, const  long long value)
{
    struct node *snode = stree->root;
    if (!snode)
        return NULL;
    while (value != snode->info) {
        snode = snode->child [value > snode->info];

        if (!snode)
            break;
    }

    return snode;
}

void turn (struct node **tnode)
{
    struct node *b = NULL;//балансируемый узел
    struct node *a = NULL;//ребенок балансируемого узла
    struct node *c = NULL;//ребенок узла а
    struct node *beta = NULL;//подветка узла с
    struct node *hama = NULL;//подветка узла с или а

    b = *tnode;

    short dir = (b->balance < 0);//направление
    short mod = (dir) ? 1: -1;//модификатор, зависящий от направления

    switch (b->child [dir]->balance * mod) {//операции поворота одни и теже, но происходят зеркально, взависимости от направления
        case -1: case 0:
            a = b->child [dir];
            hama = a->child [!dir];
            a->child [!dir] = b;
            b->child [dir] = hama;
            *tnode = a;

            switch (a->balance * mod) {
                case -1:
                    b->balance = 0;
                    a->balance = 0;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    b->balance = -1 * mod;
                    a->balance = 1 * mod;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            a = b->child [dir];
            c = a->child [!dir];
            beta = c->child [!dir];
            hama = c->child [dir];
            c->child [dir]= a;
            c->child [!dir]= b;
            a->child [!dir]= hama;
            b->child [dir]= beta;
            *tnode = c;

            switch (c->balance * mod) {
                case -1:
                    b->balance = 1 * mod;
                    a->balance = 0;
                    c->balance = 0;
                    break;
                case 0:
                    b->balance = 0;
                    a->balance = 0;
                    c->balance = 0;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    b->balance = 0;
                    a->balance = -1 * mod;
                    c->balance = 0;
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return;
}

struct tree *del_tree (struct tree *rTree)
{
    rTree->root = (rTree->root) ? del (rTree->root) : NULL;

    rTree->size = 0;
    free (rTree);

    return NULL;
}

struct node *del (struct node *rNode)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
        rNode->child [i] = (rNode->child [i]) ? del (rNode->child [i]) : NULL;
    }

    free (rNode);

    return NULL;
}
```

Вкратце: я использую массив указателей на avl-деревья в качестве таблицы, при добавлении элемента ячейка массива находится с помощью хэширования,после чего в дерево вставляется значение. Но, программа кушает слишком много памяти: при `n = 10000000, x = 0, a = 1, b = 2147483648` расход где-то 320 мегабайт, что не укладывается в условие (256). Подскажите как уменьшить расход?

Comment: Инициализаторы вида `= {};` не поддерживаются в стандартном С.

Comment: Всмысле? С чего это вдруг?

Comment: В С нет и никогда не было `= {}` (именно с пустыми скобками). Это чисто С++-ная фишка.

Comment: Кстати, а приведите полные входные данные. Вы пока привели только первую строчку.

Comment: Зачем тут вообще деревья? используй обычный массив для разрешения коллизий; и будет тебе счастье... хэш конечно в кучу переложить нужно и сделать его нормального размера...

Comment: @Fat-Zer в кучу перекладывать его не обязательно - достаточно сделать нормального размера.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, в стек будучи нормально размера он не влезет... зависит от системы конечно, но, наверняка, на него более жёсткое ограничение по памяти... а в статике как-то неприятно держать такую махину.

Comment: @Fat-Zer почему неприятно? В подобных задачах это вообще-то норма.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, в олимпиадном варианте понятно что так делают, а это всё же учебная задачка... тут ИМХО надо всё же почище писать... заодно можно размер хэша подобрать в зависимости от данных...

Comment: @Fat-Zer нет смысла. Тут есть ограничение на N - на него и надо ориентироваться, остальное - от лукавого.

Answer (score 1):

(По-видимому подразумевается 64-битная платформа. Такие вещи надо указывать в вопросе.)

1. Забить на выравнивание. Упаковать структуру с точностью до байта. Не пользоваться `malloc`, а выделять память в собственном пуле для объектов одинакового размера. При `sizeof(struct node) == 25` потребление памяти должно упасть до 250 мегабайт.

   Собственно из таких соображений, очевидно, и выросло ограничение на 256 мегабайт в условии.
2. Заметить, что при 1 <= X <= 10<sup>15</sup> `info` требует только 50 бит. По алгоритму AVL `balance` требует только 3 бита (от `-2` до `+2`). Поля `info` и `balance` можно впихнуть в одно 64-битное поле одновременно. В такой ситуации не нужно манипулировать выравниванием. Свой пул для выделения памяти однако понадобится. `sizeof(struct node) == 24`и потребление памяти должно упасть до 240 мегабайт.
3. Совместить методы 1 и 2, заметив, что на пару `info` и `balance` достаточно 7 байт. `sizeof(struct node) == 23` и потребление памяти должно упасть до 230 мегабайт.
4. Заменить указатели `child` на индексы в своем пуле-массиве. При 1 <= N <= 10<sup>7</sup> каждый требует 24 бит. `sizeof(struct node) == 13`, то есть потребление памяти можно довести до 130 мегабайт.

P.S.
1. Инициализаторов вида `= {}` нет в стандартном С. Должно быть `= { 0 }`.
2. Должно быть `signed char balance;`, а не `char balance;`.

Comment: Что касается char - в моей системе он signed, но замечание принято во внимание. Короче нужно уходить в поля - я правильно понял? И еще: почему {} не поддерживается? Я все время им пользовался, да и в книге Прата именно так указывалась инициализация.

Comment: Да, и хотел спросить, что означает "выравнивание" в этом контексте?

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch:В С нет и никогда не было `= {}`. Где именно вы в книге Прата такое увидели? А то, что GCC это разрешает - не более чем развеселая студенческая самодеятельность. "Выравнивание" и "упаковка" в данном случае идут рука в руку: как только вы начнете паковать структуру, то поедет и выравнивание в "плотном" аллокаторе.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под "уходить в поля" не совсем ясно. Для первого варианта было бы достаточно какого-нибудь `#pragma pack(1)`, но `malloc` все равно будет выделять по 32, скорее всего. Для второго и третьего варианта это тоже критично. Так что "уходить" тут надо в первую очередь в свой аллокатор.

Comment: Ясно,  благодарю.

Comment: Да, кстати, по поводу платформы: прога должна работать на двух - тобиш у меня 64, но проверка происходит на 32

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch то что тип char у вас знаковый, не отменяет того что char и signed char являются разными типами данных. Как и не отменяет возможных других настроек на проверяющем компьютере.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch переключите у себя локально чтобы компилятор компилировал под 32 бита. Потребление памяти снизится.

Comment: Не совсем понял что переключить? Задача, в принципе, уже решена - через хеш с открытым ключом, но мне все же интересно как уменьшить объем памяти в данном случае.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Входные данные дайте целиком, которые у вас дают 320 мегабайт  - чтобы можно было протестировать альтернативные варианты.

Comment: Их же много! Там тысячи комбинаций - да и зачем?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Именно чтобы попробовать одну из возможных модификаций и посмотреть на ее потребление памяти.

Comment: Первое условие во второй строке: 1 1 0 0